# Use a method from another class ? without opening new form?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, methods

Hey guys my issue is that i can't use the common class `class1 = new class();` and just do `class1.method1();` because if I make a new instance of the class it would open a new form and the class also has a constructor. I just need that one method from the class nothing more.

Comment: Not all classes are forms.

Comment: so how and where did you call this class? please share your codes.

Comment: Please post the code of the class, also it's likely your class inherits from a form class.

Answer (score 1):

To use a class' instance method, you need an instance of that class; no exceptions*. If its constructor opens a form, make it so that it doesn't.

Comment: * Reflection might be able to hack it through. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to re-consider your design pattern as if this `class1` you speak of is a Form then stopping the UI from showing in such a manner is not a particularly proper design pattern. Update your question with your current implementation so people can better advise you!

If you are manually instaniating and displaying a Form from within the `class1` constructor you could consider an implementation like this:

> ```
> public Class1(bool showForm)
> {
>     if (showForm)
>     {
>         //Show UI
>     }
> }
> ```

If you must you could hide the UI like so:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    base.SetVisibleCore(false);
}
```